# Swapping array contents by key in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array, where contents are added by key instead of index.

In playing around in a sandbox I notice the following:

- Even though I add contents to the array via key (instead of index), the contents do not show up and the length is 0 (even though they are there)
- I cannot seem to swap the contents between array items.

Is there a rule I'm unaware of when using keys instead of indexes to see the contents and to swap contents?

I made a bare-bones fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/26Lve48g/

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blah: [],
  },
  created() {
    this.blah['abc'] = 'foo';
    this.blah['def'] = 'bar';
  },
  computed: {
    // Correctly shows the value in the HTML window
    blahAbc() {
      return this.blah['abc'];
    },
    // Correctly shows the value in the HTML window
    blahDef() {
      return this.blah['def'];
    },
  },
  methods: {
   swap(a, b) {
     const tmpA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.blah[a]));
     const tmpB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.blah[b]));
     Vue.set(this.blah, this.blah[a], tmpB);
     Vue.set(this.blah, this.blah[b], tmpA);     
   }
  },
})
```

Comment: Are you looking for an object instead of an array?

Comment: Li357 - blah is an array. The contents of the array can be anything. keys are being used instead of indexes

Comment: Right. If you want non-numeric keys why are you using an array? It does not track non-numeric keys. Use an object and count the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] uses numeric and string values as index,

> Though, elements added using string indexes can only be regarded as
>   properties of the array object and not true array elements.

Length property as well as array methods are only applied to the elements with numeric indexes

Read more about it here https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/associative.php

{} uses string and Symbol as keys

Although objects can be added to arrays

In your case

```
<div id="app">
 <button @click="swap('abc', 'def')">Swap</button>
 <p>Blah:{{ blah }} {{ blah.length }}</p>
 <p>BlahABC: {{ blahAbc }} </p>
 <p>BlahDEF: {{ blahDef }} </p>
</div>
```

Running the above code spits out

```
Blah:[] 0

BlahABC: foo

BlahDEF: bar
```

As you can clearly see `blah` has no numeric index so length returns 0.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/szu7f4hn/
It swaps the contents of the array on button click.

Comment: I can clearly see the output of this.blah['abc'] in the computed call, so it is getting added somehow. Can you please explain how that is working?

Comment: JS is not a statically typed language. Variables can be assigned any type of value anytime e.g var a = 1 can be reassigned a="test" string.

Comment: In your case even though you declare it as an array when you say blah['abc'] it changes to an object

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 check out the code in the edited answer

Comment: Interesting. I was under the assumption you could use an array of keys as sort of a hashtable

Comment: Surprisingly, the explanation you gave isn't accurate.  The `typeof` any array is always `object`.  One accurate way to test for an array is: `variable instanceof Array`.  Test `this.blah` at any point in his code and you will see it's always true.  Try an array method such as `forEach` on it at any time and it will show you the array keys (this would throw an error for an object).  But log it to the console and you will see all the keys plus the string key.  I'm surprised myself.  Here's a fiddle demonstrating the behavior:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/r2tbm5uo/

Comment: Yes, array is a special implementation of object in JS.

Comment: Yeah.  So two things:  1) `blah` is indeed still an array.   2) You can use string keys in an array because JavaScript is weird.   But you shouldn't.

Comment: Though length property only works when we use numbers as index in array

Comment: It doesn't throw an error but it also doesn't count the string key.  It's as if the variable becomes simultaneously an array and an object, all the prototype methods of both work.  But the array methods only work on the numerical keys.